# How to make simply date picker

Tags: html, angular, forms

at this moment in my html I have something like this:

```
<div class="label">Date of birth</div>
  <div class="d-flex">
    <div class="form-group col-md-4">
      <select id="inputState" class="form-control margin-no-left">
        <option selected>Day</option>
        <option>1</option>
        <option>2</option>
        <option>3</option>
        <option>4</option>
        <option>5</option>
        <option>6</option>
        <option>7</option>
        <option>8</option>
        <option>9</option>
        <option>10</option>
        <option>11</option>
        <option>12</option>
        <option>13</option>
        <option>14</option>
        <option>15</option>
        <option>16</option>
        <option>17</option>
        <option>18</option>
        <option>19</option>
        <option>20</option>
        <option>21</option>
        <option>22</option>
        <option>23</option>
        <option>24</option>
        <option>25</option>
        <option>26</option>
        <option>27</option>
        <option>28</option>
        <option>29</option>
        <option>30</option>
        <option>31</option>    
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-4">
      <select id="inputState" class="form-control margin-left">
        <option selected>Month</option>
        <option>1</option>
        <option>2</option>
        <option>3</option>
        <option>4</option>
        <option>5</option>
        <option>6</option>
        <option>7</option>
        <option>8</option>
        <option>9</option>
        <option>10</option>
        <option>11</option>
        <option>12</option>   
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-4">
      <select id="inputState" class="form-control margin-left-double">
        <option selected>Year</option>
        <option>1984</option>
        <option>1985</option>
        <option>1986</option>
        <option>1987</option>
        <option>1988</option>
        <option>1989</option>
        <option>1990</option>
        <option>1991</option>
        <option>1992</option>
        <option>1993</option>
        <option>1994</option>
        <option>1995</option> 
        <option>1996</option>
        <option>1997</option>
        <option>1998</option>
        <option>1999</option>
        <option>2000</option>
        <option>2001</option>
        <option>2002</option>
        <option>2003</option>
        <option>2004</option>
        <option>2005</option>
        <option>2006</option>
        <option>2007</option> 
        <option>2008</option>
        <option>2009</option>
        <option>2010</option>
        <option>2011</option>
        <option>2012</option>
        <option>2013</option>
        <option>2014</option>
        <option>2015</option>
        <option>2016</option>
        <option>2017</option>
        <option>2018</option>
        <option>2019</option>   
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group col-md-4">
    <label></label>
    <select id="inputState" class="form-control">
      <option selected>Country</option>
      <option>Australy</option>
      <option>Austria</option>
      <option>Belgium</option>  
      <option>Canada</option>
      <option>France</option>
      <option>Germany</option>
      <option>Holland</option>
      <option>Italy</option>
      <option>Poland</option>
      <option>Spain</option>
      <option>United Kingdom</option>
      <option>United States</option>  
    </select>
  </div>
```

This implementation taking a lot of code, somebody can tell me how to make simpler picker for birthdate? I just want to make simply as possible - without any windows for pick a date. I wondering about months too - some of them have 31 days, some 30,29,28 - how to prevent to pick unwanted values?

Comment: What is stopping you from using `<input type="date">`?

Comment: @AnuragSrivastava https://caniuse.com/#feat=input-datetime

Comment: Shows pretty good support in major browsers, apart from IE and Safari, which are known to be outdated. In any case OP doesn't mention about browser support, so I don't see how relevant that link is.

Comment: @AnuragSrivastava because picker is ugly in my opinion, I wan't to achieve it like this or to style picker on my own.

Answer (score 2):

if you are using Angular, please save the values for date, month, year and country, each in a separate array in your component ts.. loop them in your component html using **ngFor**

for example,
component ts,

```
this.dropdowns = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
```

component html,

```
<select>
    <option *ngFor='let item of dropdowns'>{{item}}</option>
</select>
```

the above should render you an output html of,

```
<select>
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
    <option>4</option>
    <option>5</option>
</select>
```

in the above format, you can update your dropdowns..

Answer (score 1):

there's a awesome datepicker in the own Materia Angular, or in ng-bootstrap. but If you want to make one youself, first use arrays

imagine that you has an array like:

```
months= [
      {name:"January",days:31},
      {name:"February",days:28},
       ...
      {name:"December",days:31}
    ]
```

As angular must iterate over arrays, we are going to have a fool array. And add a initialYear and an object "date" where we are going to store the variable

```
foolArray=new Array(31)
initialYear=new Date().getFullYear()-20;
date={day:1,month:0,year:this.initialYear}
```

Finally we need two functions, One to see if a year is a leap year and another to check is a date is valid

```
  isLeap(year:number)
  {
    return new Date(year,1,29).getMonth()==1
  }
  checkDate()
  {
    let date=new Date(this.date.year,this.date.month,this.date.day);

    if (date.getMonth()!=this.date.month)
    {
      this.date.day=this.date.month==1?
          this.isLeap(this.date.year)?29:28:
          this.months[this.date.month].days
    }
  }
```

Well, we are going to put all the select using [(ngModel)]. But we need remember that a select return a string, so we are going to separate the "banana notation" in [ngModel] and (ngModelChange)

```
<select [ngModel]="date.day" (ngModelChange)="date.day=+$event">
  <option *ngFor="let t of foolArray| slice : 0 :months[date.month].days;let i=index">{{i+1}}</option>
  <option *ngIf="date.month==1 && isLeap(date.year)">29</option>
</select>
<select [ngModel]="date.month" (ngModelChange)="date.month=+$event;checkDate()">
  <option *ngFor="let month of months;let i=index" [value]="i">{{month.name}}</option>

</select>
<select [ngModel]="date.year" (ngModelChange)="date.year=+$event;checkDate()">
  <option *ngFor="let month of foolArray;let i=index" >{{i+initialYear}}</option>
</select>
```

See how use slice pipe to show the days of the month and how add 29 if is a leapYear and we are in "Febrary". Yes. Another thing we need take account is that I use 0 for January, 1 for Febrary...

This allow as has in a getter a function like

```
  get Date()
  {
    return new Date(this.date.year,this.date.month,this.date.day)
  }
```

That return our date in the way of Date javascript object.

See in [stakblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dcw2cr?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

NOTE: Perhafs is interesting convert our component in a Custom Form Control implementing ControlAntecesor